# gdal_translate SQLite driver has no raster capabilities

Tags: raster, gdal, spatialite, sqlite, rasterlite

I am trying to convert a raster to SQLite using rasterlite2 and gdal a la:

`gdal_translate -f SQLite raster.img raster.sqlite`

but after running the command I get the following error:

`ERROR 1: SQLite driver has no raster capabilities.`

---

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and have installed the following with `apt install`

- gdal-bin
- libgdal-dev
- sqlite3
- spatialite-bin
- libspatialite-dev
- rasterlite2-bin
- librasterlite2-dev

I thought these are the only dependencies, but maybe I am missing something?

Does anyone spot anything missing?

Comment: GDAL has to be compiled/built with [librasterlite2](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html#:~:text=libsqlite3%2C%20librasterlite2%2C%20libspatialite) it's not available by default and it looks like the GDAL package in Ubuntu was not compiled with it.  You could try a GeoPkg raster https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try GPKG or MBTILES (Raster Tiles in SQLite)

GPKG can be any SRS /Projection and is organized in XYZ
MBTILES is always 3857 Web Mercator and is organized in TMS

They are standard map tiles 256x256 pixel images in tile_data blob
with integers zoom_level, tile_column,tile_row

GPKG adds supporting tables and can include more than one table of tiles (just named differently)
MBTILES is only one table named tiles and a metadata table.

use gdaladdo to add the upper zoom levels/overviews